# Skipping Arduino code in a 'while' statement

Tags: arduino

I am trying to build a [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) for my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) with an [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). I am using [Arduino simulator](http://virtronics.com.au/Simulator-for-Arduino.html) to debug my code. Here is where I got the problem in the `loop()` function:

```
void loop() {
    while (!ConnectServer());
    while (client.connected()) {
        int i = 0;
        char c = 'o';
        while (client.available()) {
            c = client.read();
            if(c == ';')break;
            commandBuff[i++] = c;
        }
        commandBuff[i] = '\0';          //Skip this line
        ParseCommand(commandBuff);      //And this line
    }
    if (!client.connected()) {
        client.stop();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when it gets a `;` from the input. It not only breaks out of the internal loop, but it also skips the two code lines outside of the internal while loop. And goes back to the conditional statement of the external `while` loop....

I don't think this has something to be do with `ConnectServer()`, but still I am pasting the code for it too:

```
bool ConnectServer() {
    char response;
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        client.println("EHLO");
        response = client.read();
        if (response == 'e') {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

How do I fix problem?

Comment: What makes you think the two lines are getting skipped?

Comment: I am single stepping through the code.

Comment: That's very odd. Have you tried doing a clean build of the code (i.e. from scratch)?

Comment: Clean build? I am using the simulator not the device...

Comment: That still involves compiling the code, right?

Comment: No, it does not seem to compile the code. Rather it starts the code directly with out compiling it.

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint in `ParseCommand`, it's never hit?

Comment: No, this simulator does not allow break points, all you can do in it is to run the code or single step from start to end....

Comment: The problem, as it seemed to be, is with the simulator?

Comment: Yes, that what it looks like. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: So is there any other way I can debug my code?

Comment: yes, run it using an actual arduino, and use debug printouts to identify if the workflow is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Any idea about the problem?*

Your code looks clean, and if you're not convinced it is, you can still replicate what you wrote in C that you can compile and debug on your computer, by creating a few mockup classes that emulates behaviors of `client`, `Serial` etc.. (which is the kind of things Arduino simulator certainly does).

Most of the Arduino simulator I've found are not *really* simulators (unlike `qemu` or even `vmware` for real OS), they just parse the code and hardcode some features of the Arduino library. That's why they often do not support advanced stuff, or not even the full C language and even worst (as it looks to be your case) introduce bugs.

So, as I commented out, you should better use a real Arduino, and debug your code using debug printout statements, or using an AVR debugger.